# different vs. various vs. several

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which of the following are correct? As a non-native English speaker they seem interchangeable to me, but I wonder if in the context of the sentence they have a different meaning to each other.

*Explored different methods for topic modeling such as LSA and LDA.*

*Explored various methods for topic modeling such as LSA and LDA.*

*Explored several methods for topic modeling such as LSA and LDA.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of your examples can be correct, but there are differences in meaning depending on which word you use.

Explored **different** methods....

Each method is unique and distinct from the other methods. This could include methods that are not specifically topic modeling methods (perhaps you're applying a technique from another discipline to propose a unique solution).

Explored **various** methods...

The methods are different, but share some commonality at a very high level. In this case, the commonality is that the methods are all topic modeling methods.

Explored **several** methods...

This only refers to the number of methods explored. It makes no assumptions about similarity or difference. It is often combined with **different**, for example:

We explored **several different** methods for topic modeling...